# How to match two parts of error message and concatenate them?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, errorformat

I try to read [:h errorformat](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#errorformat):

```
%m              error message (finds a string)
```

I try to read it, but I practically found that it's impossible to specify `%m` twice:

```
E372: Too many %m in format string
```

I want to match ctest output, that looks like so:

```
1/1 Test #1: testname ...........***Failed  Required regular expression not found.
```

I can match it with like:

```
 :let &errorformat='%\d%\+/%\d%\+ Test #%l: %f %[.*]%#Failed  %m'
```

and that will give me:

```
 testname|1| Required regular expression not found.
```

This is no ideal, as it will try to open `testname` file that does not exists. But I want to match `Test #1: testname` and the message and remove the `....***Failed` part, so ideally, I would want like:

```
 :let &errorformat='%\d%\+/%\d%\+ (Test #%l: %f)%m %[.*]%#Failed  %m'
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ like concatenates this to %m
```

Do I have to use an external tool (`Filtering messages` section from `:h errorformat`) (it will be `sed`) or is it possible to get `%m` twice and concatenate the message within vim errorformat?

Comment: Considering help says _The ... "%m" conversion [has] to detect the end of the string._ and all the examples show it as the last `%` item it looks like a direct approach is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that.

Indeed, using an external tool to format the message is the way to go. The tool can be simple, `sed` is more than enough.

Another option is including the whole line in the message by ab-using `%+` operator, like:

```
let &errorformat='%+G%\d%\+/%\d%\+ Test #%l: %f %[.*]%#Failed  %m'
```

will result in:

```
 testname|1 error| 1/1 Test #1: testname ...........***Failed  Required regular expression not found.
```

But this is a workaround - it will start a multiline message, but never end it, there may be problems with `%C`.